# Erlang list generation

Tags: list, erlang

I have 2 list:

> ["asd", "dsa"].
>
> [[123, "asd"], [4534, "fgh"]].

How can i generate next list: I ned list that tail of each nested list =:= other element of 1 list.

In this example:

> ["asd", "dsa"].
>
> [[123, "asd"], [4534, "fgh"]].

"asd" =:= "asd" ->

Output list:

```
[123, "asd"]
```

I try:

Here S = [[123, "asd"], [4534, "fgh"]].
D = ["asd", "dsa"].

> List = lists:filter(fun(X) ->
>   lists:last(X) =:= D end, S),

But D in this example list, and i need element of list.

How can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
1> [X || X<-[[1,2,4],[7,8,3],[2,5,4],[9,1,6]], Y<-[4,3], lists:last(X)=:=Y].    
[[1,2,4],[7,8,3],[2,5,4]]
```

Or, using your sample data:

```
2> [X || X<-[[123,"asd"], [4534,"fgh"]], Y<-["asd","dsa"], lists:last(X)=:=Y].
[[123,"asd"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more direct way of writing it would be:

```
lists:filter(fun (X) -> lists:member(lists:last(X), D) end, S).
```

or with list comprehensions:

```
[ X || X <- S, lists:member(lists:last(X), D) ].
```

They are a little faster as they will not attempt to match against more elements in `D` if the element is found. Expanding `D` in the comprehension will do this.